# How to store the printout of the last command in a shell variable in urxvt/zsh?

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, stdout, rxvt

I'd like to have the printout (stdout and stderr) of the last command run within zsh available in a variable ready to use `grep`, etc on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect output from a command into a file (or even a variable), but that does not happen automatically.

Redirecting output is a large topic in the manual page.  Just to remind you of the term, this redirects both standard output and error:

```
foo=$(command 2>&1)
```

checked by

```
$ foo=$(oops 2>&1); date; echo "$foo"
Sun Feb 28 20:59:18 EST 2016
sh: 1: oops: not found
```

Further reading:

- [3.6 Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) (Bash Reference Manual)

Comment: Hi, I know how to assign to variables in shell script. Do you have any idea how to run such a code for each executed command automatically?

Comment: It's conceivable that a shell could be written to do this.  Someone might know of one.  Your usual choices: bash, zsh (probably cannot do this without essentially writing a new prompt/execute interpreter).

Comment: Do you think there is a way to have zsh prefix every command with a `tee` that store a copy of the output to a file (while still running the command in interactive mode)? Would it be possible to write a zsh plugin to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a pager to capture output and then quit if it fits on one screen.  When it doesn't fit, you can use the pager to scroll and search.

```
export PAGER=less
export LESS=-FSXRi
# -F and -X are relevant here, but that's what I use
# also, less quickly toggles most by typing '-' and the option
```

I imagine zsh has a way to automatically modify commands to go through a pager, but I don't know how.

Compare this output to a different directory that fits on one screen:

```
find ~ -type f |& less
# |& to capture both stdout and stderr
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could also just `tee` every command into a file but as you pointed out the problem is how to make zsh append this automatically.

Comment: One advantage of a pager over tee is you don't mess with files for short output, but can review, save, or bail if it's more than a screenful. I use a one-letter alias and just type it on the end of some commands.

Comment: @danijar Apparently you can do it with a [preexec function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15488779/2957469).